# XAML Binding of related objects

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I have 2 class like this

```
class X {

    int IdOfX;
    string NameX;
    string etcX;

    int IdOfY;
}

class Y{

    int IdOfY;
    string NameY;
    string etcY;

    int IdofX;
}
```

These classes are now simplifying those I have in my project...I cant use a variable of type of class X because this classes have to be serialized to json and imao this will cause trouble because class X has a Member Y and class Y has a member X so this will end up in a loop ...

```
public List<X> xs { get; set; } = new List<X>();
public List<Y> ys { get; set; } = new List<Y>();
```

and an xaml like this

```
<Grid>
  <ListView Name="lstView">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
        <GridView.Columns>
          <GridViewColumn Header="NameX" Width="100" 
                          DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NameX}" />

          <GridViewColumn Header="NameY" Width="80" 
                          DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=???}" />

        </GridView.Columns>
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>    
</Grid>
```

How can I display the name of the Y which is connected to my class X by its id?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use a view-model.  For example:

```
public class xViewModel : x
{
    public string NameY { get; set; }
}
```